# resolv.conf auto reset by dnsmasq after install libvirt-bin

Tags: 11.10, dns, dnsmasq

After I install libvirt-bin and ubuntu-virt-server, etc., my resolv.conf gets overwritten by dnsmasq about every hour.

I haven't installed network-manager and resolvconf. When I search for dnsmasq I see that only dnsmasq-base has been installed.

When I try to remove dnsmasq-base,  libvirt-bin will be removed automatically.

How to keep dns config not be changed?

I use ubuntu 11.10

thanks for every reply.

edit:

```
$ dpkg --list | grep dnsmasq
$ ii  dnsmasq-base    2.57-1ubuntu1    A small caching DNS proxy and DHCP/TFTP server

$ pgrep dnsmasq
1088
```

in my syslog file:

```
dnsmasq[1088]: reading /etc/resolv.conf
dnsmasq[1088]: using nameserver 192.168.1.1#53
```

Comment: can you check if dnsmasq is running? `pgrep dnsmasq`

Comment: AFAIK, dnsmasq doesn't modify resolv.conf. Perhaps you've also got resolvconf installed? The resolvconf package definitely *will* modify resolv.conf. You can check by running "dpkg --list | grep resolv"

Comment: I found these in my syslog file: dnsmasq[1088]: reading /etc/resolv.conf, dnsmasq[1088]: using nameserver 192.168.1.1#53

Comment: and I'm sure I haven't install resolvconf

Comment: and I searched for dnsmasq and dnsmasq-util,they are not instelled too, only dnsmasq-base is installed

Comment: pgrep dnsmasq echo 1088

Comment: Are there any references to DHCP near the dnsmasq log entries in the syslog?

Answer (score 0):

Not dnsmasq but some other package was overwriting /etc/resolv.conf. See /usr/share/doc/resolvconf/README.gz in the resolvconf package for an incomplete list of packages that overwrites /etc/resolv.conf.

As of Ubuntu 12.04 the resolvconf package is part of the base system and resolvconf mediates access to /etc/resolv.conf. See resolvconf(8).